# measurable $\{f(x)=a\}$ non-measurable $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given this definition of a Measurable Function:

A function $f$ defined on a measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is measurable, if for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, the set
$$f^{-1}([-\infty,a))=\{x\in E: f(x)<a\}$$
is also measurable.

We can easily prove that if $f$ is measurable then $\{x\in E: f(x)=a\}$ is measurable where $a \in \mathbb{\bar{R}}$ here.

Now the **converse** is not true. I am looking for counter example.

Comment: "We can easily prove..." what? You seem to have left something out here.

Comment: $g^{-1}(y)$ is a subset of $\{y,-y\}$, so it has at most $2$ elements.

Comment: You missed my point! I think you meant to say that $\{x\in E: f(x)=a\}$ _is measurable_, but you forgot.

Comment: @TonyK Oh Thanks. Fixed.